# es6 classes and multi level inheritance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

is there a restriction on multi level inheritance with es6 classes. I am adding some additional functionality to a framework/ external class.

```
class B extends External.A {
  // ...
}

class C extends B {
  // ...
}
```

and use like

```
const result = new C(data);
```

gives error

> TypeError: Class constructor B cannot be invoked without 'new'

But, if I use class `A` directly, there is no error

```
class C extends External.A {
  // ...
}

const result = new C(data);
```

// works fine

Edit:
I use `"babel": "^6.5.2"` to transpile everything. In real code, all 3 classes lives in different file and uses module system to export and import them. if that matters.

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but are you invoking `super()` in `class C constructor`?

Comment: That's because ... happens in `// ...`. Please, provide the relevant code in the question, including External.A.

Comment: no `super` call directly, but might be in the transpiled code. thanks.. I will make a standalone example. I think it also may because of `export default` and some quirk in importing them. Will give additional info.

Comment: Please provide enough code on fiddle to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please show us your whole code. The parts that you posted do work.

Answer (score 0):

### Original answer

Bare bones of your problem works like charm.
Probably your code is lack of `super()` in `constructor()`

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    document.write('from A <br/>');
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    document.write('from B <br/>');
  }
}

class C extends B {
  constructor() {
    super();
    document.write('from C <br/>');
  }
}

new C();
```

Here is fiddle you can play with: https://jsfiddle.net/nkqkthz2/

---

### Edit

In your original question you pass some data to C class constructor `new C(data);`, then if you want to handle this in your chain of classes, you should write own constructor function:

```
class A {
  constructor(data) {
    document.write(`${data} A <br/>`);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  someFunc() {
    //
  }
}

class C extends B {
  constructor(data) {
    super(data);
    this.data = data;
  }
  write() {
    document.write(`${this.data} C <br/>`);
  }
}

const c = new C('test');
c.write();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rwqgm9n0/

Pay attention that class B you don't need specify constructor since default constructor is:

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
}
```

and this can pass data to class A constructor.

---

If you omit super in class C constructor you newer pass data to class A which can produce your error.

```
class A {
  constructor(data) {
    document.write(`${data} A <br/>`);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  someFunc() {
    //
  }
}

class C extends B {
  constructor(data) {
    //super(data);
    this.data = data;
  }
  write() {
    document.write(`${this.data} C <br/>`);
  }
}

const c = new C('test');
c.write();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jwm5xjcp/

Comment: thanks. your example gave a way for me to try and it is not because of super calls. see https://jsfiddle.net/f2806fbz/1/ . I don't use explicit constructor in my code as well. It probably then has to do with how the module system exports the class. Not sure I can try it in fiddle, but do it my local setup. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Multilevel Inheritance:

```js
class Person{
 constructor(firstName, middleName, lastName){
  console.log("Person constructor........");
  this.firstName=firstName;
  this.middleName=middleName;
  this.lastName=lastName;
 }
 fullName() {
  return `${this.firstName}${this.middleName==null?' ':' '+this.middleName+' '}${this.lastName}`;
 }
}

//let person = new Person("FirstName",null, "LastName");
//console.log('Full Name: '+person.fullName());

// INHERITANCE
class Employee extends Person{
 constructor(employeeId, joinDate,firstName, middleName, lastName){
  super(firstName, middleName, lastName);
  console.log("Employee constructor........");
  this.employeeId = employeeId;
  this.joinDate = joinDate;
 }
}

/*let employee = new Employee(12, '2017-02-01', "FirstName",null, "LastName");
console.log('Full Name: '+employee.fullName());
console.log('Employee ID: '+employee.employeeId);
console.log('Join Date: '+employee.joinDate);*/

class EmpOne extends Employee{
 constructor(empOneId,employeeId, joinDate,firstName, middleName, lastName){
  super(employeeId, joinDate,firstName, middleName, lastName);
  console.log("EmpOne constructor.........");
  this.empOneId = empOneId;
 }
}

let newEmpOne = new EmpOne("emp one ID", 13, '2018-02-01', "FirstName",null, "LastName");
console.log("==================================")
console.log('Full Name: '+newEmpOne.fullName());
console.log('Employee ID: '+newEmpOne.employeeId);
console.log('Join Date: '+newEmpOne.joinDate);
console.log('EMP ONE: '+newEmpOne.empOneId);
```

Comment: in this code , super used in EmpOne class will have access to which classes? Immediate parent or both the parents ?